# facebook friend invites - who sent invitation

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app where each user can invite his friends to join the app.

I have done this via the JS FB SDK.

I also use PHP SDK for server sessions and other things.

Now the questions is how can I determine the id of the inviter when an user joins my app based on the invitation sent?

EG:
Let's say USER-X invites USER-Z to join my app. Then USER-Y invites USER-Z to join my app too. But USER-Z joins through the link of USER-X. I want to reward USER-X because he brought a new user to my app, so I need his fbid or something. How can I do determine the referer?

I have used this code to implement the Facebook friends invite on my website:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 FB.init({
  appId:'<?=APPID?>',
  cookie:true,
  status:true,
  xfbml:true
 });
  function FBInvite(){
  FB.ui({
   method: 'apprequests',
   message: 'Invite your Facebook Friends'
  },function(response) {
   if (response) {
    alert('Successfully Invited');
   } else {
    alert('Failed To Invite');
   }
  });
 }
</script>
```

```
<a href="#" onclick="FBInvite();">OPEN INVITE POPUP</a>
```

Comment: you have to keep the records of the invitees and the invites and when they join depending on the url through which they are joining you can be able to determine the referer

Comment: I agree, but this is not done on server-side so I cannot store any token for an invitation which I can use later. I have read that the facebook invite feature can be done only via JS and not on server side. So I cannot know in advance which user received an invitation and which didnt and who sent it.

Comment: a unique token is required to identify who the referer is so I guess then you have to implement it on server side

Comment: Just request the request object details from the API when a user acts upon an invite …

Comment: @CBroe - you mean when an user clicks on an invite and he is redirected to my app, should I then request the object details based on the invited user? What value should I find useful?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1#reading